# Animate viewpager visible view to full screen on scrolling the current visible view

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I have a viewpager which displays a next and prev views as preview. Each displayed view has a scrollview. Since my viewpager shows preview there are some padding and margin given for the viewpager. Now what i need to do is, On scrolling the view of the visible item the viewpager the view should become animate and become full screen. I tried adjusting the padding and margin on scroll but its not working. Is there any other way to get that.

achieved the view pager animation using the following code[image]

```
    final float MIN_SCALE = 0.90f;
    final float MAX_SCALE = 0.95f;

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        page.setTranslationY(0);
        float scaleFactor = MIN_SCALE + (MAX_SCALE - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - Math.abs(position));
        page.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
    }
```

Now the visible view has scrollview. On scrolling it should become full screen by some smooth animation.